# "Access is Denied" accessing a subpage in ASP.net (hosting with IIS)

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I'm getting the current error when trying to go to any page other than the index:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       Access is denied.
>       Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.
>       Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
>       Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

There is no login system for my site.  Only one small database.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can hit the root page but not the others I'd be concerned about NTFS permissions.  Check out the tip for the anon user as p.campbell is suggesting.  I THINK you'll find that you're ok for anonymous at the IIS level, but you probably only granted appropriate file permissions to your "index" page and need to propagate those permissions to the rest of the files/directories in question.

Edit:  Here's a link that goes through some basics for NTFS permissions.  It boils down to your worker identity needing read access at least.  By default, that identity is either ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICE, depending on OS.  YOu can configure your application pool to be something else if you want though:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815153

Comment: Just like you would check permissions if you weren't troubleshooting a website issue.  Right click the root of your website in windows explorer -> properties -> security.  I think I have a bookmark laying around that goes through common settings for new .NET sites.  Your anon user and .net worker identity both need access.  Edit:  Found link, updated answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you propagate the changes to all child folders by starting at the Security tab mentioned above -> click Advanced button -> Change Permissions -> Replace all child object permissions...

Comment: Sadly, hardly anything from IIS 6.0 matches with 7.0 :(

Comment: These are just NTFS permissions.  The only thing different with the various IIS versions is the name of the user you have to grant rights to.  The same basic concept applies regardless.  If you don't have an ASPNET user, try NETWORKSERVICE.  Failing that, check the actual identity that your application pool is running as.

Comment: When a request comes in, it gets handled by IIS.  If the user isn't authenticated, they come is anon.  IIS will stop you right there if anon isn't configured for access by IIS.  Next, assuming all is well, IIS passes the request to the .NET runtime.  If .NET has to do anything, like read an .aspx file off the file system, it needs a user account.  The user account that it operates under is the identity assigned to the .NET application pool.  By default, this is ASPNET or NETWORKSERVICE, depending on your OS/IIS version.  I think the .NET application pool identity has insufficient credentials.

Comment: Note things can get a little muddy with integrated mode, but I don't think you need to get in to that right now...  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Does your host and its control panel support the enabling/disabling of Anonymous access?
It sounds as if 'Anonymous' is disabled.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1152085.aspx

Comment: According to IIS, Anonymous access is enabled :)